# is there way to do bulk update using pyodbc using executemany

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to do bulk update and bulk insert of 120 rows in to SQL server using pyodbc using below code

`INSERT` is taking around 2 sec where as update is taking 80 seconds.
Is there a better way to do bulk update? please guide

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={cfg.SQL_DRIVER};SERVER={cfg.SQL_SERVER};PORT=. 
{cfg.SQL_PORT};DATABASE={cfg.SQL_DATABASE_NAME};UID={cfg.SQL_USERNAME};PWD=. 
{cfg.SQL_PASSWORD.}')
cursor = conn.cursor()      
params = [tuple(x) for x in data.values]
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(self.query, params)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Query is ``` query = f"""UPDATE table set cloumn1=? where cloumn2 =? 
            and column3 = ? and column4 = ? and analysis_id = ? 
            and column5 = ? and column6 = ? and column7=? and column8=?"""```

Comment: Does the table have indexes defined that are appropriate for supporting your update query?

Comment: yes,indexes are defined that are appropriate for supporting update query

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/741

Comment: i have 2 environment.one environment the batch update taking 2 sec.for the same amount of data in another environment it is taking 60 sec.